# PL/SQL FOR loop after the WITH statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, common-table-expression

I wrote a WITH statement as follow

```
with tempTable as ( select t1.c1, t1.c2, t2.c3 from (t1 join t2))
```

`select * from tempTable` gives me:

| c1 | c2 | c3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| circle | blue | alpha |
| circle | red | beta |

I want to use this statement in a query where for each of the records the data in the columns from the tempTable is used. I use `select 'Random text' from DUAL` and `UNION ALL` to add rows to my result. The result is used further in another programming language. This is a example of what i want to get.

```
Random text
circle is shape
circle has color blue and red
Random text
```

And I want to achieve the third line with  a loop like. I dont have permisson to create a view thats why I have to stick to the with statement.
The problem is that after the with statement a select is expected.
i tried with

```
BEGIN 
   for i in (select * from tempTable) LOOP
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (i)
   END LOOP
END
```

The problem is I cant access from the loop to the tempTable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`temptable` is not table but it is CTE. you can use it directly in the loop as follows:

```
BEGIN 
   for i in (select * from 
               (with tempTable as 
                   ( select t1.c1, t1.c2, t2.c3 from (t1 join t2)) 
               select * from tempTable)
            ) LOOP
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (i);
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: The problem is that a select statement is needed right after with with statement. i have more of those loops which i have to use in my code thats why i wrote the with statement in the first place to avoid writing the whole select again and again

Comment: Then you should use the cursor or use GTT. WITH can not be shared between multiple queries